# Отмена выполнения функции после некоторого времени в Swift

Tags: swift, функции, таймер

Доброго времени суток, как можно отменить выполнение функции после некоторого времени ожидания её выполнения?

Например, есть функция

```
func someLogic()
{
    //some code
}
```

Хотелось бы не ждать её выполнения, а написать что-то вроде

```
cancelAfter(time: 0.1) { someLogic() }
```

Comment: Для таких целей хорошо подходит NSOperation. Документация:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

//тип возврата или значение или timedOut
typealias Result = (`data`: Any?, error: DispatchTimeoutResult? )


// метод с задержкой
func collMyMethod(_ timeOut: DispatchTime, complition: @escaping (Result) -> Void) {

    // создаем асинхронный поток
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        //создаем группу
        let group = DispatchGroup()

        // входим в группу
        group.enter()

        // вызываем метод и когда он завершится выходим из группы
        myMethod { (returnValue) in
            complition((returnValue,nil))
            group.leave()
        }

        // устанавливаем timeout для группы
        let result = group.wait(timeout: timeOut)
        switch result {
            case .timedOut: complition((nil,.timedOut))
                break
            default: break
        }
    }

    return
}

func myMethod(complition: @escaping (ReturnType) -> Void) {
    //что-то дулаем и оно вызавает complition()
    complition("sdfsdf")
}


// пример вызова
collMyMethod(.now() + 10) { (result) in
    if let error = result.error {
        print(error)
    } else {
        print(result.data!)
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня не получается использовать Ваш вариант. Для тестирования изменил содержимое func MyMethod: 

    ``func myMethod(complition: @escaping (Int) -> Void)
    { 
     print("Press any key")
     let key = getKeyPress() 
     print(key)
     complition(key)
    }``

Функция getKeyPress() возвращает int-значение нажатой клавиши.

При исполнении кода в консоль не выводится ничего.

Comment: а вы в плейграунде пробовали или в проекте ? У меня в плейграунде не работает а вот в проекте работает